# How to get content of javascript without putting its source?

Tags: javascript

Supposedly I have a `<script>` tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/public/assets/v1/javascripts/min/main.js"></script>
```

I want to get the content of "localhost/public/assets/v1/javascripts/min/main.js", echo it between the script, without actually putting the `src` attribute, is it possible to do this?

Comment: Open the HTML document in a text editor and paste it in? I'm really not clear on what it is you hope to achieve.

Comment: Only if it's on the same domain, with ajax.

Comment: @Benjamin: yes same domain, how to do with ajax?

Comment: @user2002495 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/16825593#16825593

Comment: @Quentin: I'm trying to hide the source of my js files in the dom element

Comment: @user2002495 — Stop wasting your time. There is no way to hide the JS that the browser parses.

Comment: Ajax won't solve that.  You can just view the ajax call by viewing the source or pressing F12 and watching the network traffic.  I agree with @user2002495, get familiar with F12.

Comment: What could you possibly need to hide? You could always just obfuscate your code to make it difficult for humans to read...

Comment: The only way I know of to do this is an absolutely terrible idea. You would load the JS as text and then use `eval` to interpret the scripts. However, this is easily done using a server-side language like PHP and includes to add the code without disclosing its file system location.